# Run Android aapt on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to build an Android project on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine, 64 bit.
For some reason, after I've done everything required, I still can't run "aapt".

As instructed, I downloaded the SDK and installed all the packages.
I changed permissions on the file, and also installed 32->64 bit multiarch libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```

Because this didn't work, and after a whole lot of more searches, I also installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

Still, I get

```
aapt: command not found
```

Please let me know if there's anything else to attach to the question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to consider [JafarKhQ's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19623295/1198661).
It works for me.(Ubuntu 12.04 64bit)

Answer (score 0):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120644/run-android-aapt-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit#comment34778509_18120644) by [Sinhyeok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198661/sinhyeok): [JafarKhQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124691/jafarkhq)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19623295/1201863) works for us, which is:

> sudo apt install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1

Answer (score -2):

You might be missing the android sdk from your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this has nothing to do with the PATH as I'm trying to run an executable from the directory itself.